# htaccess, rewriteurl to page of WordPress site in sub-folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Here's the scenario, I have a single server and two WordPress sites living in their respective sub-folders:

```
public_html/site_one/
public_html/site_two/
```

These sites display as follows:

```
www.site.com/site_one/
www.site.com/site_two/
```

The second of those sites has a splash page / landing page:

```
www.site.com/site_two/landing-page/
```

...that needs to display in the root of the site:

```
www.site.com/
```

I'm aware that there are better ways of achieving this, but I'm restricted to working with how it's currently set up.

Initially I thought I would be able to set up a .htaccess file in the root that rewrites access to the root of the site to display the landing page from site_two, but this isn't working as expected. This is the .htaccess file from the root of the server:

```
RewriteRule ^$ subfolder/page-slug [L]
```

This redirects to the site's front page. If I replace `page-slug` with `?p=1234` then it displays as the correct page but also seems to redirect to the landing page's full URL.

Is there any means of achieving what I'm after?

To clarify:

1. User visits site.com
2. URL displays as site.com
3. Page displayed is site.com/site_two/landing-page/

I've managed to have this behaviour working when not linking to a WordPress page (using a test index.php in 'test-subfolder') but WordPress and its own .htaccess file seems to be confusing matters.

Any help would be appreciated. Is there a way of excluding the landing page from the WP .htaccess file and what is it about the WP .htaccess file that's stopping the page being displayed at the root of the site?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, I'll let you know if I figure it out.